# Is there a way to associate the value of a row with another row in Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel

I created a df from the data of my excel sheet and in a specific column I have a lot of values that are the same, but some of then are different. What I want to do is find in what row these different values are and associate each one with another value from the same row. I will give an example:

```
 ColA      ColB    
'Ship'      5
'Ship'      5
'Car'       3
'Ship'      5
'Plane'     2
```

Following the example, is there a way to find where the values different from 5 are with the code giving me the respective value from ColA? In this case would be finding 3 and 2, returning for me 'Car' and 'Plane', respectively.

Any help is welcome! :)

Comment: so 'ship' is always 5, car is always 3?

Comment: do you have a list of the true values each item is supposed to be?

Comment: maybe you can give an example of the data inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on exacty what you want to do, but you could use:

- a filter - to filter for the value you seek.
- `.where` - to show values which are False.

Given the above dataframe the following would work:

```py
df['different'] = df['ColB']==5
df['type'] = df['ColA'].where(df['different']==False)
print(df)
```

Which returns this:

```
    ColA  ColB  different   type
0   Ship     5       True    NaN
1   Ship     5       True    NaN
2    Car     3      False    Car
3   Ship     5       True    NaN
4  Plane     2      False  Plane
```

The 4th column has what you seek...